# Higher-order web frameworks/add-ons for Twisted/Cyclone/Tornado (web login/user/admin)?

Tags: python, flask, twisted, tornado, cyclone

I'm struggling with some architectural choices for a scalable internet-of-things application.

I've chosen to base my project on [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com) augmented with the [Cyclone](http://cyclone.io) framework to provide many [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) convenances (websockets, auth-decorators, secure-cookies, etc)

Using a Twisted core has worked beautifully for me. I have numerous IP protocol and hardware interfaces all of which turned out to have great library support inside of twisted (and adding new protocols and interfaces to my application are the most-likely angles I'll have project scope creep), all with Twisted needing very low CPU and providing for very high connection counts.

My problems are with second-order webapp functionality.

I pulled in Cyclone thinking that with it's auth goodies (OpenID, oauth, user-auth decorators and secure-cookies) it wouldn't take much to implement user/session/admin functionality in my webapp.  After the 500+ lines of abstracting my database (via [txmongo](https://github.com/fiorix/mongo-async-python-driver)) and *just* building user logins it became clear I both:

1. Didn't understand how little Cyclone/Tornado bring in the user/session/admin space, and
2. Didn't understand the amount of code it takes to fill in the gaps if your trying to build a multi-user auth webapp

A friend pointed me at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), which initially I thought was completely redundant, until I found [flask plugins](http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/).  The combination of [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org) and [Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org) would completely cover my user, session and user-admin needs, negating me writing what I would guess to be about 2k lines of code.  Unfortunately, the flask plugins are all rife with blocking code and calls to blocking libraries. I don't see them as compatible with my project even if [WSGI](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wsgi.html) [containers](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html) are used given that the user/session functionality happens with every page load (additionally I don't see any short cuts that would allow me to port them to async world without work roughly equal to that of rewriting them)

My question is:

In the python async space (... hopefully in the Twisted space, given my protocol needs), are there any plugins or alternate frameworks that provide ready-to-go user/login/admin functionality similar to what is in Flask-Login and Flask-Admin?

P.S. I've looked at [Klein](https://github.com/twisted/klein) as the obvious Twisted version of Flask, but it doesn't seem to have a plugin ecosystem, and I'm not finding any strong user/session/admin there.

P.P.S. By the time I wrote this question I had already written my own (crappy) user-login-session system. So what I'm really after is the "Admin" capability (automated CRUD functions on user-style records, including web UI rendering, all designed in a Twisted/async way).  I asked about user/login in the question in case it turn out there is an already-integraded solution (such as flask-login and flask-admin) in which case I would happily drop my code and switch to that.

Comment: There are a few folks out there who have tried adding session support to Tornado, though they all seem to be no longer maintained: https://github.com/milancermak/tornado, https://github.com/diogobaeder/pycket. I haven't used either so I'm not sure of their quality. You may be able to borrow some code, at least.

Comment: flask-socketio has the async support. look at this: http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: You don't really need the admin to be completely async right? In that case you can use Flask-Admin in a twisted WSGIResource. As for the session stuff, I came here looking for the same answer :)

Comment: @Mike Lutz: This sounds like you are trying to push a lot of responsibility on the web-server. My biggest suggestion would be to mention to you that not everything has to run on the same library, or as the same instance.

Comment: @dpn I don't understand why you would not want to do async. If you're using twisted you've probably got a real good use case to go async. Mixing in sync code is a bad idea. I'm also looking for user management in twisted. It's as far as I can see the biggest lacking in the twisted ecosystem.

Comment: Sjuul Janssen - async is about scale, if you need to scale your admin interface beyond the thread pool provided by twisted, then so be it, that doesn't stop you from using twisted from flask admin though.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need everything async? Consider async WebSockets but sync page renders. If you must, add an async downstream proxy or load balancer which will virtually eliminate app server's IO overhead.